# incompatible types: inference variable E has incompatible bounds: failed to initialize ChoiceBox

Tags: javafx

I don't understand why this doesn't work when I try to initialize ChoiceBoxes.

```
@FXML
private ChoiceBox<?> humanChoiceB;

String[] numbers = new String[]{"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"};

humanChoiceB.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(numbers));
```

When I compile, the stated error shows up:

```
incompatible types: inference variable E has incompatible bounds
equality constraints: capture#1 of ?
lower bounds: java.lang.String
```

The weird thing is, the same piece of code works on one of my NetBeans native projects, but not on my current Maven project (also on NetBeans IDE, or say NetBeans Maven).

Tight schedule. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration

```
@FXML
private ChoiceBox<?> humanChoiceB;
```

should be

```
@FXML
private ChoiceBox<String> humanChoiceB;
```

Comment: What a silly missing! Thanks Dude. I may need to take a break.